# Service instance count in Azure Fabric Service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to find out number of instances of a servicetype that are running in a fabric service cluster at any give time through code? One way is to look at the ApplicationManifest file and get the number of instances set in that, but it might be overwritten sometimes by a parameter file. Any ideas here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to examine your services programatically then look at [FabricClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient) which exposes a number of operations that could show you the status deployed services. For your specific question, get the number of running instances, have look at [FabricClient.QueryClient.GetReplicaList...(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.queryclient.getreplicalistasync?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_FabricClient_QueryClient_GetReplicaListAsync_System_Guid_System_String_System_TimeSpan_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), it will give you a list of replicas (in the case of StatelessServices, that would be the same as instances).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you know where can I find the partitionId guid for that function ? I mean - I created a partition , but I have only lowkey, highkey - but nothing called partitionId .

Comment: You could enumerate all the partitions for a StatefulService with [FabricClient.QueryClient.GetPartitionList...(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.queryclient.getpartitionlistasync?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_FabricClient_QueryClient_GetPartitionListAsync_System_Uri_). This will give you the actual ids (guids) for the partitions. For Stateful services, you have *no of instances = partitions x replicas*, for Stateless you will most of the time only have one partition (Singleton).

Comment: Thanks . I did it. I was hoping for a better solution. Will use this. Thanks!